# Transaction rollback management into forEach with nested try/catch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, rollback

Given this top level function :

```
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public MoveAndBlockStockResponseDto moveAndBlock(final String locationId, final String userId, final String systemId,
                                                   final MoveAndBlockStockRequestDto moveAndBlockStockRequestDto) {

    final var movements = moveAndBlockStockRequestDto.getMovements();

    // Address fetching from requestBody
    final List<String> addressesSource = movements.stream()
        .filter(it -> BIN_SOURCE.equals(it.getSourceType()))
        .map(MoveAndBlockRequestObjectDto::getSource).toList();

    final List<String> addressesTarget = movements.stream()
        .filter(it -> BIN_TARGET.equals(it.getTargetType()))
        .map(MoveAndBlockRequestObjectDto::getTarget).toList();

    final var addresses = Stream.of(addressesSource, addressesTarget).flatMap(Collection::stream).toList();

    // Container fetching from requestBody
    final List<String> containerSource = movements.stream()
        .filter(it -> SSCC_SOURCE.equals(it.getSourceType()))
        .map(MoveAndBlockRequestObjectDto::getSource).toList();

    final List<String> containerTarget = movements.stream()
        .filter(it -> SSCC_TARGET.equals(it.getTargetType()))
        .map(MoveAndBlockRequestObjectDto::getTarget).toList();

    final var containers = Stream.of(containerSource, containerTarget).flatMap(Collection::stream).toList();

    // Conversion to DTO
    final Map<String, AddressV2> addressV2Map =
        customAddressV2Repository.findAddressesWithAll(locationId, addresses).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(addressV2 -> addressV2.getId().getAddressId(), Function.identity()));

    final Map<String, ContainerV2> containerV2Map =
        customContainerV2Repository.findContainerWithAll(locationId, containers).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(containerV2 -> containerV2.getId().getSscc(), Function.identity()));

    // Validation before performing update
    final MoveAndBlockDto moveAndBlockDto =
        validateMoveAndBlock(moveAndBlockStockRequestDto, addressV2Map, containerV2Map);

    final MoveAndBlockStockResponseDto response =
        performMoveAndBlock(locationId, userId, systemId, moveAndBlockDto, addressV2Map, containerV2Map);
    moveAndBlockDto.getErrors().forEach(error -> response.getErrors().add(error));

    return stockMapper.toMoveAndBlockStockResponseDto(response);
  }
```

This method is calling performMoveAndBlock method, such as :

```
  public MoveAndBlockStockResponseDto performMoveAndBlock(final String locationId, final String userId,
                                                          final String systemId,
                                                          final MoveAndBlockDto moveAndBlockDto,
                                                          final Map<String, AddressV2> addresses,
                                                          final Map<String, ContainerV2> containers) {

    final MoveAndBlockStockResponseDto response = new MoveAndBlockStockResponseDto();
    final List<MoveAndBlockResponseObjectDto> success = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<ErrorMoveAndBlockDto> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    moveAndBlockDto.getStocks().forEach(
        stock -> {
          try {
            updateStockClass.updateStock(locationId, userId, systemId, addresses, containers, success, errors, stock);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            errors.add(errorMoveAndBlockDtoMapper.setErrors(e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), stock));          }
        }
    );

    response.setStocks(success);
    response.setErrors(errors);
    return response;
  }
```

Which is calling this method, in another class so the @Transactional annotation can work :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateStock(String locationId, String userId, String systemId, Map<String, AddressV2> addresses,
                   Map<String, ContainerV2> containers, List<MoveAndBlockResponseObjectDto> success,
                   List<ErrorMoveAndBlockDto> errors, MoveAndBlockRequestObjectDto stock) {
      // Case when source is an address && target is an address
      if (isSourceAnAddress(stock.getSourceType()) && isTargetAnAddress(stock.getTargetType())) {
        updateStockAtAddressSource(addresses, stock);
        success.add(updateStockAtAddressTarget(locationId, userId, systemId, addresses, containers, stock));
      }
      // Case when source is a container && target is an address
      else if (isSourceAContainer(stock.getSourceType()) && isTargetAnAddress(stock.getTargetType())) {
        updateStockAtContainerSource(containers, stock);
        success.add(updateStockAtAddressTarget(locationId, userId, systemId, addresses, containers, stock));
      }
      // Case when source is an address && target is a container
      else if (isSourceAnAddress(stock.getSourceType()) && isTargetAContainer(stock.getTargetType())) {
        updateStockAtAddressSource(addresses, stock);
        success.add(updateStockAtContainerTarget(locationId, userId, systemId, containers, stock));
      }
      // Case when source is a container && target os a container
      else if (isSourceAContainer(stock.getSourceType()) && isTargetAContainer(stock.getTargetType())) {
        updateStockAtContainerSource(containers, stock);
        success.add(updateStockAtContainerTarget(locationId, userId, systemId, containers, stock));
      }
    }
```

What I want is that if an exception occurs in one of the two methods of an if statement, it rollbacks the operations made in database ONLY for one stock processed into the forEach method.

To be honest, I don't understand why the rollback is not performed (I purposedly launched a NPE into the function `updateStockAtContainerTarget`, what I can see is that an error is thrown but the changes in database performed by the `updateStockAtAddressSource` is not rollback in database.